# How to make data access layer for SQL Server and MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, architecture

I'm building a data access layer and need to be able switch between two providers in different environments.

How do I structure this? I'm using a repository pattern and have e.g. a `CarRepository` class and a `Car` class. The `CarRepository` class is responsible for saving, deleting and loading from the database.

I have a `Database` class, responsible for connecting to the database, and executing the query (sending a `SqlCommand` for SQL Server). The SQL syntax for the underlying databases is different and the parameter syntax is also different (SQL Server uses `@` and MySql uses `?`).

I would like an approach where I can make the least effort in making my application run on both platforms.

The obvious method is making a `MySqlCarRepository` and a `SqlServerCarRepository`, but that introduces a heavy amount of maintenance. Are there any good approaches to this scenario? Maybe keeping a static class with static strings containing the SQL statements for the different SQL flavours? (how about parameter syntax then?)

Any advice is welcome

(Please note that ORM (Nhibernate, Linq2Sql etc) is not an option)

Comment: Can you explain why ORM isn't an option?

Answer (score 2):

The approach I follow is to first-of-all use the ADO Provider Factories to abstract the data access implementation.  So I will use `IDbConnection` and so forth in the code.

Then I have an abstraction for a query.  I can then use `Query` objects that contain the actual sql statements.  These `Query` objects are created from `RawQuery` or various query builders (insert/update/delete/etc.) that have implementations for each provider type.  The specific raw queries will need to be coded and obtained specific to the DB you need since there is no gettin passed that.

There is quite a bit of leg work involved in coding this 'plumbing' and I have not had a situation where I actually require different platforms so I have not bothered coding some small bits that I know need some ironing out but you are welcome to contact if you are interested in seeing some code.

Comment: I would like to see some code please, can you insert sample into answer or mail me at h4mm3rhead at gmail dot com. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Can you use any code generation tools?

I used to use **Code Smith** in another life and had templates that would generate POCO objects from DB tables, repository classes for each object and stored procedures. Worked alright after fine tuning the templates, and there were plenty examples on the net.

But this was way before I saw the light with **NHibernate**!

Answer (score 0):

A pattern for accessing multiple database types is the DAO (Data Access Object) pattern. This could suit your particular need if you can't/don't use an ORM. The following article explains the pattern for Java but it is still very relevant for C#:

http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html